# Laravel 8 Undefined Variabel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, crud

I'm still a beginner in Laravel, and I'm confused by this error.

> Undefined variable: today (View: D:\Documents\My
> Project\todo-app\resources\views\edit.blade.php)

This my error
[image]

this my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required|string|max:25',
            'finished' => 'nullabel'
        ]);

        $home = Home::find($id);
        $home->title = $request->input('title');

        if($request->has('finished')){
            $home->finished = true;
        }

        $home->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $home->save();

        $mytime=time::now();
        $date=$mytime->toRfc850String();
        $today= substr($date, 0, strrpos($date, ","));
    
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
        return redirect('/home', compact('homes'), [
            'title'=>'Home',
            'date' => $date,
            'today' => $today
        
        ]);
    }
```

What should I do in my controller? is calling $today correct? I'm so confused please

Comment: in your controller where do you define $today & $ date ?

Comment: I've updated controller, but there's still no change

Comment: You are not calling the view but a route and this isn't how it works.

Comment: How to calling $today if not in the view?

Answer (score 1):

All things are right, but does not declare the variable for today($today)
Even the date variable is also declared. That one also you should be declared.

```html
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title' => 'required|string|max:25',
            'finished' => 'nullabel'
        ]);
        //This line added
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $home = Home::find($id);
        $home->title = $request->input('title');

        if($request->has('finished')){
            $home->finished = true;
        }

        $home->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $home->save();

        return redirect('/home', compact('homes'), [
            'title'=>'Home',
            'date' => $date,
            'today' => $today
        
        ]);
    }
```

Then its works 100%.....
Happy Coding and thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Soory sir,  I already added. But still no change sir

Comment: Now, what type of error is showing, after updating the code.
Can you able to share the screen shot

Comment: still no change sir, after update. But it seems my error is in the way of calling $today, how do I call $today if it's on routes?

Comment: Someone commented this to me. "You are not calling the view but a route and this isn't how it works."

Answer (score 0):

```
 $project = new Project;
        $cities = City::all();
        $states = State::all();
        $amenities = Amenity::query()->active()->get();
        $brands = Brand::all();
        $unit_types = UnitType::query()->active()->get();
        $accommodations = AccommodationType::query()->active()->get();
        return view('admin.projects._form', compact('project', 'cities', 'states', 'amenities', 'brands', 'unit_types', 'accommodations'));
```

You can send multiple variable like above code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).